# display refreshed data on hidden div after from submission with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using the following code to submit a form and then slide down a hidden div to display the submitted data.

```
  $(function () {

    $('#people_edit').on('submit', function (e) {

     tinyMCE.triggerSave();

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'people.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
        $('form')[0].reset();
        $("#people_edit").slideUp("slow");
        $("#people_detailed").slideDown("slow");
       $("#people_detailed").load("people_stoixeia.php?id="+$targetID );

        }
      });

    });

  });
```

the problem is that i am getting the old data (those before the form submission).
if i refresh the page i can see the edited(new) data.

is  there a way to refresh the #people_detailed div, before loading the data?
or maybe another workaround?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `$targetID`?

Comment: on the form that's being submitted

Comment: What..? Where are you setting the value in form, to variable `$targetID`..??

Comment: no. the variable is set in the php page that's already loaded. but that's not the issue. the form is working properly. the problem is how to get the edited data displayed  without refreshing the page.

Comment: I'm guessing that the value of `$targetID` is changing only when you refresh the page, when `PHP` creates it. `PHP` have no role in client side. If you want to change it without refreshing the page, you should change it using client side script.

Comment: actually the value of $targetID is not changing at all. it's not supposed to. all the other variables included in the form are changing if edited. but i can see the changes only after refreshing the page, which is something i dont want to do...

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
$("#people_detailed").load("people_stoixeia.php?id="+$("#thisID").val());
```

Answer (score -1):

You are loading your data twice - with the jQuery.ajax call and .load().
Why not just to load data to your DIV inside your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'people.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('form')[0].reset();
        $("#people_edit").slideUp("slow");

        $("#people_detailed").html(data).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

This code suppouse that people.php returns the data your need after doing what it do in your case.

Comment: He is sending the request to one file and loading from another file.

Comment: I saw that, but it is possible that he doesn't know that this could be made within the same file and the same ajax call.